# Scrolling A Video Bar In A Horizontal Bar: Touch Screen Conflict

Tags: scrolling, touchscreen

Using a touch-screen device on a site with a horizontal scroll bar and an embedded video: I find it extremely difficult to scroll the video's time bar. The horizontal scroll bar conflicts. Is there a work-around to this?

Here's a 1 minute video example:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/2u9iqp7rxnqkcjl/scrolling.mp4?dl=0

EDIT: This happens on Chrome and Firefox too:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw7qg3w8julfzfk/surface-2.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

You are using Edge, which is well-known for such problems.
I list below the usual advice that is given by Microsoft for such complaints,
although do not expect miracles.

- Clear browsing history
  In Microsoft Edge, select Hub > History > Clear all history.
  Select Browsing history and Cached data and files, and then select Clear.
- Clear all browsing data
  In Microsoft Edge, select Hub > History > Clear all history.
  Select all the boxes, and then select Clear.
- Repair or reset Microsoft Edge
  Repairing the browser won't affect anything, but resetting will remove history, cookies, and any settings you might have changed. You'll find these options in Settings > Apps > Microsoft Edge > Advanced options.
- Reset Edge the hard way
  Delete the contents of this folder:
  `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`,
  or for safety just stash them somewhere else.
  This requires Administrator permission.
- Reset edge to default settings via reinstall
  Open PowerShell as Administrator and execute this command :

  ```
  Get-AppXPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register “$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml” -Verbose}
  ```

If no solution can be found within Edge,
you could always try another browser.
I would recommend using Chrome or Firefox.
Chrome is currently the best in multi-threading parallel execution,
so might best fit your needs.

Comment: I tried on fresh installs of Chrome and Firefox. They didn't work either. Proof here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dw7qg3w8julfzfk/surface-2.mp4?dl=0

Comment: What is the tablet? It looks as if when a video is being played, it just about uses the entire CPU.

Comment: What gives you the impression that the whole CPU is being used? It's a Surface Book 2, with an i7 and 16 gb of RAM.

Comment: The freeze is abnormal. Maybe a bad codec.

Comment: It never froze. Tapping the video can act as play or pause. Because it wouldn't register my scrolling attempts, it was treating them as taps instead.

Comment: Yes, but everything else seems from your videos to become unresponsive, as if all the resources of the computer were used up.